# Reset Bootstrap table rows to "stripe" style

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to display a table. My current functionality is to have the user select a row in the table, and then a form on the page gets populated with information from the selected row.

I'm also trying to make it so that the user can explicitly see which row was selected.

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "white").css("background", "royalblue");
    $("tr").not(this).css("color", "black").css("background", "white");
});
```

The problem is, I am also using Bootstrap's `table-striped` class, and the jQuery above overwrites any of that, which means the style has to be re-applied.

I know there are workarounds for this like only styling the row's foreground text, but I'd really prefer to change the background of the whole row to make it stand out more, if it won't be too much of a hassle.

I do not know exactly what colors Bootstrap uses for the striped table, and it seems redundant to reimplement the stripe colors in the above jQuery.

Is there a relatively easy way to "reset" the rest of the table so that all non-selected rows adhere to the Bootstrap striped table rule?

Comment: Don't change the css. Add and remove a class instead.

Comment: @Malk so I added this class in my stylesheet:

    `tr.selected { color: white; background: royalblue; }`

And in jQuery:

    `$(this).addClass("selected");`
    `$("tr").not(this).removeClass("selected");`

But when a striped row is selected, it does not change the background color, only the foreground color. It only works for non-striped rows.

Comment: Try `tr.selected>td { color: white; background: royalblue; }`

Comment: Okay, that worked. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Malk for your help. Here is what I added to my CSS file:

```
tr.selected > td {
    color: white;
    background: royalblue;
}
```

And in jQuery:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("tr").not(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').css({ color: 'inherit', background:'inherit' });
```

or

```
$('tr').removeAttr('style');
```